# Type casting through string

Tags: swift

I want to instantiate a class where its name is in a variable:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName) as UIViewController
```

I need to cast the view controller:

```
if let specificViewController = viewController as? <what goes here?>
```

Please, how do I get the type for casting?

Comment: You can't. A type cast is evaluated at compile time and must be a constant. By the way the bridge cast `as UIViewController` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can type cast to either the base class, in this case UIViewController, or you can use the class you assigned to the view controller in the storyboard.

To do so, navigate to the  file, locate the view controller of interest and see what Class you assigned to it in the Identity Inspector.

Update:

Swift can't handle this type of dynamism you're asking for, this was possible in objective-c but not in swift. You could use the `NSSClassFromString` method to get the class from a variating string, but its return type is still `AnyObject` so there's no point.

The workaround you can use in the current state of swift is either:

- Create a base class that has all the required methods you'll share across inheriting VCs

or

- Create a protocol that achieves the same

Then, you can instantiate to either one, and call all the methods you'll need.

Comment: I should have made it clear that "viewControllerName" is a variable.  It will be assigned many values as each controller name passes though this code.  There is no single view controller of interest.  There are many view controllers and all their names will pass through this code.  I need to get the class type from the string variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up with this:  switch on the string and hardcode the storyboard ID per case.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: From the storyboard**

If you have a specific class for the view controller it is usually displayed in the storyboard

[image]

So I would use (for InstructionVC)

```
if let specificViewController = viewController as? <what goes here?>
```

**Method 2: Programatically**

If you have set the Storyboard ID (as I did) you can programmatically find this

```
var str: String! = self.restorationIdentifier
```

**Personally I would use the first method**